Making sense of the connection between different equations for the chemical potential
I've been studying thermodynamics and I'm a little confused on some of the peculiarities of the chemical potential. On the one hand, we have for the free energy (or Gibbs energy with $+PV$):
$$F = E - TS + \mu N$$ (1)
With $\mu = \left( \frac{\partial F } {\partial N} \right)_{V,T}$ or $\left( \frac{\partial G } {\partial N} \right)_{P,T} $ .
On the other hand we see equations like:
$$F=\sum_i \mu_i N_i$$ (2)
for the free energy of a mixture. In a single component $ F=\mu N$, which is a result on Euler's theorem of extensive functions. But, how is (2) consistent with (1) ? Where does the "$E -TS$" "go"?
Also, upon taking the derivative of the free energy one keeps $T$ and $V$ fixed and as such some contributions to the free energy are "hidden away" when performing the derivative to obtain $\mu$. Seeing that the differential of $F$ can be expressed as:
$$dF = dE - SdT + \mu dN $$ (3)
in a canonical ensemble, it follows that for a fixed $T$ derivative the second term vanishes and for fixed $V$ we have no performed work which is one of the contrbutions to $dE$. Nevertheless, according to (2), the chemical potential contains all information on the free energy besides a multiplicative factor $N$ (I'm thinking one-component here). How is this consistent with the fact that when keeping T and V (or T and P for that matter) constant we are "hiding" some information when calculating the chemical potential?
What am I misunderstanding?
Thank you for the help

Let's start with the definition of chemical potential $\mu$ (This is the definition my college professor used when teaching physical chemistry):
$$\mu:=\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial N}\right)_{T, V}$$
In your question you said,

... (3)
in a canonical ensemble, it follows that ...

First, I have to point out that this is a Grand Canonical Ensemble, because the number of particles is allowed to change.
Now let's derive things from the fundamentals so that your confusion will be resolved. For a grand canonical ensemble, the partition function
$$Z=\sum_{i}e^{-\beta(\varepsilon_i-\mu N_i)}$$
It's easy to derive
$$\frac{\partial \ln Z}{\partial \mu}=\beta\langle N \rangle$$
Recall that in a canonical ensemble, free energy
$$F=-\frac{1}{\beta}\ln Z$$
For grand canonical ensemble, it's tempting to have such a formula. The equivalent is Landau free energy (a.k.a. grand potential) $\Phi$:
$$\Phi=-\frac{1}{\beta}\ln Z$$
Taking its partial derivative with respect to $\mu$,
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial \mu}=-\langle N \rangle$$
Now it's naturally to understand the common definition of grand potential $\Phi$:
$$\Phi=E-TS-\mu N$$
We have
$$d\Phi=dE-TdS-SdT-Nd\mu-\mu dN$$
Since
$$dE=TdS-pdV+\mu dN$$
We get
$$d\Phi=-pdV-SdT-Nd\mu$$
$\Phi$ is a minimum when the system reaches equilibrium, when $V,~T,~\mu$ stop evolving.
Obviously $\mu$ depends on the condition of the system. It's not only related to the type of the substance, but also depends on $N, T$, etc.
Regarding your confusion,

Nevertheless, according to (2), the chemical potential contains all information on the free energy besides a multiplicative factor N (I'm thinking one-component here). How is this consistent with the fact that when keeping T and V (or T and P for that matter) constant we are "hiding" some information when calculating the chemical potential?

entropy obviously depends on the number of particles $N$. Let's state this explicitly. (Recall the definition $S:=k_Bln~W$, where $W$ is the number of possible microscopic configurations of the system with the given macroscopic property (e.g. $T, V, N$). )
$$F(N, V, T):=E(N, V, T)-TS(N, V, T)$$
$$dF=\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial V}\right)_{N, T}dV+\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial T}\right)_{V, N}dT+\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial N}\right)_{V, T} dN$$
$$dF=-pdV-S(N, V, T)dT+\mu(N, V, T) dN$$
If you keep V, T constant, then
$$dF=\mu(N, V, T)dN$$
$$F=\int_{0}^{N_1}\mu(N, V, T)dN$$
In your equation (2),

$$F=\mu' N$$

$$\mu'=\frac{\int_{0}^{N_1}\mu(N, V, T)dN}{N}$$
That's actually averaged, having no physical meaning. (It makes no sense to say an individual particle carries a certain amount of free energy. It depends on the system. All the particles in the system decide the freedom, i.e., number of possible microscopic configurations.)
I also found out why on many chemistry textbooks you can see
$$G(:=F+pV)=\mu N$$
In some very specific situations, $G$ is indeed proportional to $N$, with a constant chemical potential $\mu$, for example, ideal gas with $T, p$ constant. You can easily see that from Sackur-Tetrode equation.

$F_{grand} \equiv \Phi = ... + N d\mu$ is the form for the grand canonical ensemble no? That is why I said the $\mu dN$ was canonical (if N is fixed F is a minimum for the canonical ensemble), but yes I see now that that term should be in the dE and that if the particles are fixed it is irrelevant to add that term to the differentials anyway. Did I understand correct?

As for the "confusing" (IMO) chemical definition $ F=\sum_i \mu_i N_i$ I understand that the chemical potential is treated as a per particle free energy, what I don't understand is why one can drop the rest of the terms in $F=E-TS+\sum_i \mu_i N_i$. I assume if nothing else is changing they become irrelevant additions that don't affect the thermodynamics of the problem and that is why they are discarded (they become zero-points on $F$)?  Thank you for the detailed answer!

@WanderH I edited my answer. Hope it better addresses your confusion why E, T, S is thrown away in the expression of F (under conditions of T, V constant). It's quite obvious from definition but easily ignored that chemical potential itself depends on E, T, S.

Thank you! It's all clearer now!
